# Why does this code for insertion sort not work?

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

```
def insertion_sort(l):
    i = 0 ;
    while i < len(l):
        if l[i] > l[i +1]:
            l[i], l[i+1] = l[i +1], l[i];
            i = i +1;
        else:
            i = i + 1 ;
    return lst; 

lst = [34,12,56,4,90,66];

insertion_sort(lst);
```

NOTE : I am using the mobile version of Stack exchange which messes up the indentation. So please ignore that.

Comment: What's the error? What's going wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you iterate to the end of the array in the condition of your `while` loop, but you look past the end (`l[i + 1]`) in the body of the loop.

Comment: …second thing, you sort `l` and then return `lst`, which does not exist in the function…

Comment: you could also remove redundant semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working properly because you go over the array only once. There are also some minor improvements you could do. Your code should probably look like:

```
def insertion_sort(l):
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        j = i
        while l[j] < l[j - 1] and j > 0:
            temp = l[j - 1]
            l[j - 1] = l[j]
            l[j] = temp
            j -= 1

    return l


lst = [34, 12, 56, 4, 90, 66]

print(insertion_sort(lst))
```

The output would be:

```
[4, 12, 34, 56, 66, 90]
```